Want to hide few things from my terminal window in VS Code
I want to remove/hide the few things from my terminal in VS Code like when I run a code it also shows me the path of that particular folder in which I am working.
When I try to run code it runs perfectly fine but it also shows the path of the folder that I am currently working in but sometimes when I run the code it takes way too much space in the terminal and it makes me difficult to see the actual output of the code.
